# Sorting values in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a movies dataframe that looks like this...

```
title               decade
movie name 1        2000
movie name 2        1990
movie name 3        1990
movie name 4        2000
movie name 5        2010
movie name 6        1980
movie name 7        1980
```

I want to plot number of movies per decade which I am doing this way

```
freq = movies['decade'].value_counts()

#freq returns me following
2000        56
1980        41
1990        37
1970        21
2010        9

# as you can see the value_counts() method returns a series sorted by the frequencies
freq = movies['decade'].value_counts(sort=False)
# now the frequencies are not sorted, because I want to distribution to be in sequence of decade year
# and not its frequency so I do something like this...

movies = movies.sort_values(by='decade', ascending=True)
freq = movies['decade'].value_counts(sort=False)
```

now the Series freq should be sorted w.r.t to decades but it does not
although movies is sorted
can someone tell what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

The expected output I am looking for is something like this...

```
1970        21
1980        41
1990        37
2000        56
2010        9
```

Comment: freq = pd.DataFrame(movies['decade'].value_counts(sort=False)).reset_index()
freq1=freq.sort_values(by='index', ascending=True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
movies['decade'].value_counts()
```

returns a series with the decade as index and is sorted descending by count. To sort by decade, just append

```
movies['decade'].value_counts().sort_index()
```

or

```
movies['decade'].value_counts().sort_index(ascending=False)
```

should do the trick.